# cannot resolve the defined Disposable

Tags: android, rx-java2, disposable

having a function query data from database and returning a `Flowable`

```
       @Dao
        interface DataDao {
            @Query("SELECT * FROM DataTable ORDER BY `order`")
            fun listenToAll():Flowable<List<DataRoomEntity>>
        }
```

and when subscribe to it, the disposable is not resolved (see the screenshot).

```
        var dataDao: DataDao
        fun listenToDataDb(): Flowable<Data> = dataDao.listenToAll()
                .map { convertEntitiesToData(it) }

        fun getData(){
            //var disposable: Disposable? = null
            var disposable = listenToDataDb()
                    .subscribe({ data ->
                            // do something with data
                            disposable?.dispose() //<== disposable is unresolved
            }, { throwable ->
                    disposable?.dispose(). //<== disposable is unresolved
            })
        }
    }
```

but if do define the `var disposable: Disposable = null` first it is fine

```
fun test(){
            var disposable: Disposable? = null
            disposable = listenToDataDb()
                    .subscribe({ data ->
                            // do something with data
                            disposable?.dispose() //<=== it is fine
            }, { throwable ->
                    disposable?.dispose()
            })
        }
```

why it gets `unresolved` error if not define it first?

[image]

Comment: There is no reason to call dispose from within the subscribe callbacks this way. Use take() to limit the result amount if you only need some but not all from the query.

Comment: thanks @akamokd! It is said it should always call the Disposable.dispose() when the subscription is complete, and most of them recommend doing it in either onDetroy() or with `.autoDispose(LifecycleOwner.scope())`, but here it is not in fragment/activity and does not have access to the lifeCycleOwner. So thought do it at subscription's callbak, to avoid potential leak or unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

A **`Disposable`** is a stream or a link between an Observable and an Observer. You can declare globally like below

```
       lateinit var disposable: Disposable
```

Then

```
       if(!disposable.isDisposed){
         disposable.dispose()
        }
```

Comment: thanks! would you mind comment on wether to call the disposable?.dispose() inside the .subscribe()'s callback is ok? Here where it is called there is no access to context, not in activity/fragment, no viewModel so cant call .autoDispose(viewLifecycleOwner.scope()). Or what is the alternative way?

Comment: @lannyf  `When an Observable issues an OnError or OnComplete notification to its observers, this ends the subscription. Observers do not need to issue an Unsubscribe notification to end the subscriptions that are ended by the Observable in this way.` Read https://medium.com/@vanniktech/rxjava-2-disposable-under-the-hood-f842d2373e64